# Configure SQL Server connection string on somee

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, asp.net-blazor, somee

I need help, I'm trying to deploy my ASP.NET Core Blazor web assembly on somee, but I am having an issue on how to change my connection string while deploying to somee server. In my server project I have `appsettings.json` configured like this:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "server=localhost\\sqlexpress;database=xxxxxx;trusted_connection=true"
},
```

while my somee connection string goes like this:

```
workstation id=xxxxx.mssql.somee.com;packet size=4096;user id=xxxx_SQLLogin_1;pwd=xxxx;data source=xxxx.mssql.somee.com;persist security info=False;initial catalog=xxxx
```

Please how do I integrate the somee connection string into my `appsettings.json` before deployment?

Comment: Have you tried replacing the current one (which starts server=localhost\\ etc) with the somee one?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you want to keep the SQL Express connection string when running locally and switch to the other one when running on Somee. You can use appsettings transformations for that. If you don't have a file named `appsettings.production.json` already, create it. Then add the following to that file:

```json
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "workstation id=xxxxx.mssql.somee.com;packet size=4096;user id=xxxx_SQLLogin_1;pwd=xxxx;data source=xxxx.mssql.somee.com;persist security info=False;initial catalog=xxxx"
},
```

When publishing your web application to Somee you need to make sure that the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` environment variable is set to `Production`. This usually happen automatically. This will merge the changes from the `appsettings.production.json` file into the `appsettings.json` file published as part of your release. If you want to test that the update will happen as you expect it before actually deploying you can use this [Appsettings.json Transformation Tester](https://elmah.io/tools/appsettings-transformation-tester/). Also, there are some additional information about how transformations work in ASP.NET Core here: [Config transformations in ASP.NET Core](https://blog.elmah.io/config-transformations-in-aspnetcore/).

Comment: If this answer solved your problem maybe mark it as resolved?